# update panel is not working on asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my c# code behind

```
protected void callDispositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropDown = (DropDownList)ListView1.FindControl("callDispositionSelector");
    var visitID = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("visitID");
    if (dropDown != null)
    {
        Response.Write(dropDown.SelectedValue + "ssssssssss");
        visitID.Text = dropDown.SelectedValue;
    }
    else
    {
        visitID.Text = "ffffff";
        Response.Write("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
    }               
}
```

this is my asp code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        <tr class="footer" runat="server">
                            <td colspan="4" runat="server">* By VoiceMpower
                               <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"  ID="callDispositionSelector" OnSelectedIndexChanged="callDispositionChanged" clientidmode="Static">
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Disposition Reason</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Change of Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Cancellation</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="4">Wait List</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
                               </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="visitID" clientidmode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                         </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when I change the value of the select, the function is executed, but the results (the post back page) has the select in the devaul vaule.

#### note

i already have

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />
```

#### note 3

that asp code exist in `item template` in `asp.listview`

#### Note2

I can't debug the project because the database on the server and I am not allowed to make a link to it. So each time i develop a functoin, I go and deploy the website on the server and test it. So please let your answers without making break points and something like that. thanks in advance

Comment: what you have in your page load method?

Comment: @Damith I have code but nothing about it, the code is to load data to another table. this select is completely new to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Conditional Mode which means, the update panel will not work, unless the event is triggered.

Remove that.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <tr class="footer" runat="server">
                    <td colspan="4" runat="server">* By VoiceMpower
                           <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="callDispositionSelector" OnSelectedIndexChanged="callDispositionChanged" ClientIDMode="Static">
                               <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Disposition Reason</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Value="1">Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Value="2">Change of Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Value="3">Cancellation</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Value="4">Wait List</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem Value="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
                           </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="visitID" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I am already changing the test of the input (test box) please see my code,

Comment: It is the id of the text box, `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="visitID" clientidmode="Static"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: after your update: do you imply that I have to use this `</ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="callDispositionSelector" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: you are cooooooooooooool, now the select value is saving its previous value, but the text box has no value although I gave it value in both `if` and `else`

Comment: no sorry, it doesn't work. Although the select is saving its previous data, but I have something sooooo weird now. there is another select is showing at the top of the page. I mean the same select is showing again at the top of the page.

Comment: remove that `Response.Write()` stuff

Comment: also keep in mide please , that i already have trigger in another place in the page. (maybe this information helps)

Comment: I am pretty sure i read somewhere that setting client id mode to static screws up update panel. Remove it and use `<%=visitID.ClientID%>` in js Instead.

Comment: @AmitJoki when I put the even in the trigger, I got this exception `Could not find an event named 'callDispositionChanged' on associated control 'callDispositionSelector' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel3'.` before, I was make the even on the select not on the trigger, also, please what did you edit in your new  code?

Comment: @AmitJoki in this way now, the select saves its previous value, but the input doesn't have any text. and the big problem and the weirest one is that there is another select is showing, this new select is exactly the select that we are working on, I mean there is 2 selects apprears when I change the value of the select, if you don't get me please tell me because my english is bad sorry

Comment: wait you removed the trigger, i will try again

Comment: Copy the code exactly. I've also removed the `UpdateMode="Conditional"`

Comment: and you removed the auto post back,

Comment: excellent, the second weird select is gone, and the select is saving its previous value. but the input text is empty. why please?

Comment: remove this line: `var visitID = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("visitID");`

Comment: @AmitJoki when I remove it, i got error that the visitID is not exit, that is because all the above code is in listview.

Comment: @AmitJoki what do you thing of what @ Banana has said in a comments here in this answer?

Comment: Are you using the id in javascript?

Comment: @AmitJoki no at all, I just use it in c#.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @AmitJoki I will try to use another name, then I will try to check if the result from `listview.findcontrol` is null, make the select to the first value, if not make the select to the last value, and I will tell you. I will accept your answer, please keep help me in this last thing, thanks

Comment: @AmitJoki I have an idea, the select is saving its value because in your last code, there is no past back. it seems that the functions is not executed now after you removed the auto post back, right?

Comment: @AmitJoki when I write the trigger, a new select is shown, :( :(